# How to set stylesheet on QFileDialog?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qfiledialog

I'm trying to set my `QFileDialog` style sheet but is has not effect. Here is the code:

```
dial = QFileDialog()
dial.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())
path = dial.getOpenFileName(self, "Specify File")
```

Any ideas why this don't work?

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you execute the above code?  Do you receive an error of some sort?

Comment: Nope, the getOpenFileName window is white - standard windows, where as I wanted it to be dark gray with some other changes. The style has background-color/color and other parameters in it specified. Just trying to get the theme of app constant and I could not ever edit the QFIleDialog look so just though its time to ask...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to always set parents and use the inheritance of style sheets wherever possible. That way you can also use the static functions of `QFileDialog`.

I can confirm [ekhumoros suspicion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733220/1536976) that the native file-dialog ignores the stylesheet. It indeed does on Windows.

Here the example using the Qt's built-in file-dialog.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def show_file_dialog():
    QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(b, options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

b = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Test')
b.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: yellow }")
b.clicked.connect(show_file_dialog)
b.show()

app.exec_()
```

which looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Calling `setStylesheet` on an instance of `QFileDialog` has no effect when you use the [static functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#static-public-members). Those functions will create their own internal file-dialog, and so the stylesheet will be ignored.

If you want to use your own stylesheet, you will need to use the file-dialog instance you created:

```
    dial = QFileDialog()
    dial.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())
    dial.setWindowTitle('Specify File')
    dial.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
    if dial.exec_() == QFileDialog.Accepted:
        path = dial.selectedFiles()[0]
```

However, this may mean that you get Qt's built-in file-dialog, rather than your platform's native file-dialog.

PS:

If you **do** get the native file-dialog and the stylesheet has no effect on it, the only work-around will be to fallback to Qt's built-in file-dialog. To do that, just add this line:

```
    dial.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```

Comment: Instead of `dial.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())` why not just using the parent and the inheritance of style sheets. `dial=QFileDialog(self)`?

Comment: @Trilarion. Because I just didn't think of it :) I suppose I got distracted by the native file-dialog issue.

Comment: Hey, turns out all I needed was `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)`, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also for C++ version , the DontUseNativeDialog option works fine.

```
QString text = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(parent,
                                                        tr("title message"),
                                                        folder_path_string,
                                                        tr("filter (*.extension)"),
                                                        nullptr,
                                                        QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
```